# Calling multiple objects with a method in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a calendar using Java GUI and I want to create a method to create the cells of each date. Is there any way to create a method to create a bunch of JTextAreas without manually creating each individual cell?

Creating a cell one by one I do:

```
public void createCell() {
    cell1 = new JTextArea(CELL_DIMENSIONS, CELL_DIMENSIONS);
}
```

Comment: If you already know how to create a cell manually, your next step is to learn how to use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many ways of doing that one possibility would be to create a `List` inside the method with the assistance of a `for` loop and make the method return it for you to use somewhere else.

```
public List<JTextArea> createMultipleCells(int numOfCells) {

         List<JTextArea> cells = new LinkedList<JTextArea>();

          for(int i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++){
            cells.add(new JTextArea(CELL_DIMENSIONS, CELL_DIMENSIONS));
          }

         return cells;
    }
```

Same thing with an array:

```
public JTextArea[] createMultipleCells(int numOfCells) {

             JTextArea[] cells = new JTextArea[numOfCells];

              for(int i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++){
                cells[i] = new JTextArea(CELL_DIMENSIONS, CELL_DIMENSIONS);
              }

             return cells;
        }
```